# Jenkins - How to forward the result into the next build?

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I'm trying to transfer the console result to the next build like here:

Build 1 Show services:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:CI  {Get-Service | where {$_.Status -eq "running"}}
```

Build 2 sentMail:

Here I need the results of the last build to send them to the user xy..

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is it a freeStyleJob or a pipeline?

Comment: It's  a freestyle project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) first.

1. You should save result of your command as properties (for example `env.properties`) file
   in format:

   NAME_OF_ENV_VAR=content

where "content" is what you want to send to another job with escaped newlines inside.

2. Inject this variable to build with help of [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) from properties file.
3. Enable trigger of next job with current build variables (You can explicitly declare this env as parameter with any name to be more verbosive).
4. Next job should have build parameter to get this variable.

Consider to use pipelines: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/
as way to solve your problem. You can describe whole build chain as a script.